# File Deletion system

Tags: 14.10, delete, permanent-delete

I understand that for instance on a Windows system that when you delete a file that in fact it is not deleted as such immediately, but that the file is just marked meaning that other files can override it. This means then that some deleted files can then be recovered after their deletion.

Is there a similar system on Ubuntu? And if so is there a way to get it so that the deleted files, before their actual deletion, are encrypted or something so that if they are recovered then they cannot be read?

I am running Ubuntu 14.10.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is actually a property of the filesystem, not the OS. Most filesystems don't delete the contents since it more efficient not do so. This is true for ext4 as well. Recovering file data is, therefore, possible; metadata, on the other hand, is more difficult.

Answer (score 4):

You're looking for [wipe](http://linux.die.net/man/1/wipe).  I'm not sure if there's a way to make that the default delete handler though.

Comment: or scrub or sdelete or dd or .... any number of tools

Comment: Yes, bodhi, there are many things that try to do the same thing.

Comment: Wipe recovers data, I need something which permanently gets rid of it.

Comment: @bodhi.zazen - you would probably know better than me... is there a way to make something a default deletion handler?

Comment: Reading the second paragraph again, yep, this is what the OP asked for.

Comment: @hbdgaf all you need is an alias on "rm" I would assume.

Comment: Yes, but how would you get that to apply to graphical file managers?  That's more what I was asking about... @Rinzwind

Comment: @hbdgaf USC "secure-delete" command "srm" and create a nautilus action for deleting